# How to disable screen shutdown after 1 hour in Fedora 17 (Gnome)?

Tags: linux, fedora, display, power-management

Fedora 17 doesn't seem to have a "Never" option for the screen timeout setting.

Is it possible to disable this power-saving feature? This is for a machine showing a dashboard which should always be on.

Answer (score 3):

in shell type this

```
/usr/bin/gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver idle-activation-enabled false
```

Comment: My Fedora 18 gives me "** (process:8084): WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: The connection is closed" after running this command...

Comment: Edit: Ah had to use su - instead of just su to shift to root user.